# JQuery Datatable - Manipulating the CSS of the Colvis buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm currently using the JQuery Datatable for my .Net MVC Web-app.

I've added the default colvis button in the UI.

I have 2 questions :

1. Can we manipulate the CSS for these. Like changing the Gradient or differentiating them by color (light colour for deselected one's and dark for selected ones? How can we do that,if it's possible?
2. Can we add scrollbar to this list? As we need to scroll the entire page to view the complete list?

I was able to manipulate the CSS of colvis button by using the following code :

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dt-buttons { //css code here}
```

But I'm unable to reach to the solution to manipulate the column name buttons when the 'colvis' button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working.

I modified the buttons.dataTables.min.css file.

Here's the code :

**//Modify the background-image value as per your liking. It'll change the  // visible column-button colour. I've changed it to Green -  #76b900.**

```
div.dt-button-collection button.dt-button:active:not(.disabled), div.dt-button-collection button.dt-button.active:not(.disabled), div.dt-button-collection div.dt-button:active:not(.disabled), div.dt-button-collection div.dt-button.active:not(.disabled), div.dt-button-collection a.dt-button:active:not(.disabled), div.dt-button-collection a.dt-button.active:not(.disabled) {
            background-color: #dadada;
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #76b900 0%, #dadada 100%);
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #76b900 0%, #dadada 100%);
            background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #76b900 0%, #dadada 100%);
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #76b900 0%, #dadada 100%);
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #76b900 0%, #dadada 100%);
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#f0f0f0', EndColorStr='#dadada');
            box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px #666;
            font-family: 'Trebuchet MS',sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
```

**//To change the colour on-hover - I've changed it to #ADFF2F**

```
button.dt-button:active:not(.disabled):hover:not(.disabled), button.dt-button.active:not(.disabled):hover:not(.disabled), div.dt-button:active:not(.disabled):hover:not(.disabled), div.dt-button.active:not(.disabled):hover:not(.disabled), a.dt-button:active:not(.disabled):hover:not(.disabled), a.dt-button.active:not(.disabled):hover:not(.disabled) {
            box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px #999999;
            background-color: #cccccc;
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ADFF2F 0%, #ccc 100%);
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ADFF2F 0%, #ccc 100%);
            background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ADFF2F 0%, #ccc 100%);
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ADFF2F 0%, #ccc 100%);
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ADFF2F 0%, #ccc 100%);
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#eaeaea', EndColorStr='#cccccc');
        }
```

Comment: Couldn't add the scrollbar though.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you have already figured this out but still going ahead with the answer.

For changing the height and adding scrollbar you can change the class dt-button-collection as shown below.

```
.dt-button-collection{

    display: block;
    height: 450px !important;
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
```